# How can I sum unique rows with blended data sources in Google Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio

I have a sample DataStudio report at https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/3b445ea2-dbf6-4d8c-8ad4-9009bfee1f1c.

I have two data sources. Both data sources have a different schema but do share one `ID` field.

**`DS1`**

| ID | Name | Age | Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 23 | US |
| 2 | b | 10 | CA |
| 3 | c | 20 | UK |

**`DS2`**

| DS1 ID | Make | Model |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA | BBB |
| 1 | CCC | DDD |
| 1 | EEE | FFF |
| 3 | GGG | HHH |

The `DS1 ID` field from `DS2` is from `DS1.ID`. I am creating a blended data source combining both `DS1` and `DS2` on `DS1.ID` and `DS2.DS1 ID`.

When I add a scorecard on the `Blended.Age` it shows `99`. I assume this is because behind the scenes it creates duplicate rows like so:

| ID | Name | Age | Country | Make | Model |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 23 | US | AAA | BBB |
| 1 | a | 23 | US | CCC | DDD |
| 1 | a | 23 | US | EEE | FFF |
| 2 | b | 10 | CA |  |  |
| 3 | c | 20 | UK | GGG | HHH |

It is showing: `23 + 23 + 23 + 10 + 20` `=` `99`

I would like it to show: `23 + 10 + 20` `=` `53`.

I can't use `DS1` as the data source for the scorecard because I need the filters to work. So if I filter the blended data then the scorecard should update.

Comment: This is not possible in Data Studio. With BigQuery custom query this can be done: Filtering would only work by parameter input not by using drop down to select. Then these rows have to be put  in a `select distinct`.

Comment: Can BigQuery read data from my Google Sheet?